# Make a fluid div and another one to fill remaining space

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

is there a way to make something like this work on CSS and HTML:

Have 2 divs, both with unknown width, one dynamically expanding, the other filling the remaining space, as follows:

[image]

The structure is very basic:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="dynamic"></div>
</div>
```

The .filler will contain text and .dynamic will receive elements that should be displayed in one line (other html structures).

Is this possible?

Comment: Use percentage based dimensions? The `fill all remaining space` element would have a width of `100%`, and it would be inline with the other elements...

Comment: _"Is this possible?"_ Yes, but have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @JoshC even with both displayed as inline, a width of 100% will break the line!

Comment: @j08691 yes, actually, I've tried a lot... I just post questions here as my last resource! hehe

Comment: Then please post what you've tried so that we don't duplicate your efforts.

Comment: @gustavofritsch Yea.. just realized that wouldn't even work.. you're right.. JS might be needed for dynamic content.. else you could do something like this if it wasn't dynamic.. http://jsfiddle.net/6eqhK/ .. you might even be able to use something along the lines of table cells/rows.. eh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:table-cell` on the child divs, and use `width:100%` on the filler div.

```
#filler {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
#dynamic {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/htvr9/